# how does this function aspect work in javascript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

i am new to js but have prior understanding of c and java, i am into this course about js but i seem to be in trouble grasping the following code and how it works

```
function multiplyBy(multiplier){
     return (
      function(x){
        return x*multiplier
     } 
  );
}
var multiplyBy3  = multiplyBy(3);
console.log(multiplyBy3(10))
```

and the out ut is 30
my question is how does the function decides that 3 goes to multiplier and 10 goes to x, like in my experience with c and java, i have never seen anything like it, also if i define multiple functions inside multiplyby like i have in rerun space, with some input argument will 10 copy to all of em? thanks

Comment: [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: The function doesn't "decide". You call it with 3, then call the function it returns with 10. Search term: higher order functions.